# iOS App with tableview and search function

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar

I am writting an iOS app (updated app from an iOS tutorial). It has a view with a UITableView and a UISearchBar (thank you Ayan and Tommy). My issue now is following, the table shows all records from a core data entity, when I tap on a cell, the app shows a detail view from the selected cell. That works fine. The issue is that after using the search method, if I tap on a search result cell, the app doesn't show the detail view from the selected cell. I guess I have to determine anywhere the sender of the searched record,  but don't know how or where to include this.
This is my code at the moment, and any help or tip is welcome...Thank you

```
#import "PersonsTVC.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation PersonsTVC
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedPerson;
@synthesize searchResults;

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{

    NSString *entityName = @"Person";
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);


    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstname"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}



- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) viewDidUnload{
    self.searchResults = nil;
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    // Configure the cell...
    Person  *person = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        person = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show normal data");
        person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }








    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", person.firstname, person.surname];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Yellow"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Black"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Grey"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grey"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Red"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightBlue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Brown"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brown"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Orange"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkOrange"];
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.surname;
    //cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;
    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the person object that was swiped
        Person *personToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", personToDelete.firstname);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:personToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Person Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        NSLog(@"Creating a new person and passing it to PersonDetailTVC");
        Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        personDetailTVC.person = newPerson; 
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Person Detail Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // Store selected Person in selectedPerson property
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.selectedPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"Passing selected person (%@) to PersonDetailTVC", self.selectedPerson.firstname);
        personDetailTVC.person = self.selectedPerson;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}

- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePersonDetailTVCWasTapped:(PersonDetailTVC *)controller
{
    // do something here like refreshing the table or whatever

    // close the delegated view
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Person* person = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* firstName = person.firstname;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [firstName isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([firstName rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

Comment: Please follow the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view), specifically the section, "Sending Data to a Detail View". However, before you post this sort of queries make sure that you have done enough research or else it would only increase site burden and your question would be down voted and deleted in turn.

Comment: I have seen the recommended tutorial, but I don't find the way to solve my issue, I see that at the recommended tutorial there are two tableviews, and in my app there is only one with two different arrays, one for the normal view with all records, and one with the filtered records. I am sorry, but I need a little help...

Comment: Ok got your idea. my recommendation would be to always use the filtered result set as the datasource for the table. Filtered result set would be filtered according to the search filter that you might already have figured out. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method remove the checking `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` and use `person = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` for always.

Comment: thank you Ayan, but your proposal is not working. Thank you in any case. You have been very nice to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a segue setup in your storyboard (where you control-click dragged from the table cell to your Detail View Controller) that allows touching the regular table view cells to segue to the Detail View, however your search table view cells do not have such explicit instruction on what to do when touched.

Try adding the table view delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath and initiate a segue when a search table cell is touched:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Perform segue to detail when a SEARCH table cell is touched
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Person Detail Segue" sender:tableView];
    }

}
```

Doing so should fire off your prepareForSegue method when a search result table cell is touched. It appears you've already implemented the logic to handle the "Person Detail Segue", but we'll need to add logic to differentiate between whether the segue is coming from a selected regular table cell or search table cell.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Person Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        NSLog(@"Creating a new person and passing it to PersonDetailTVC");
        Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        personDetailTVC.person = newPerson; 
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Person Detail Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // Store selected Person in selectedPerson property
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        NSLog(@"Passing selected person (%@) to PersonDetailTVC",    self.selectedPerson.firstname);
        personDetailTVC.person = self.selectedPerson;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}
```

There may be some implementation errors on my part, but I believe this is the general strategy that may work for you. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you MFarmer, your solution works fine, very nice solution. I have learned a lot from your code.